# How to make excel function to output array

Tags: excel, sumproduct

I want to use a function within sumproduct that doesn't take an array. For example, I have this dataset:

```
+---------+----------------------------------------------+--------+-----+
|  Topic  |                      Eq                      | Weight | Val |
+---------+----------------------------------------------+--------+-----+
| Topic 1 | LOGNORM.DIST(val,2.4,0.4, FALSE)*10.2027*D50 |     13 |   5 |
| Topic 2 | val/10                                       |     10 |   4 |
| Topic 3 | val^2                                        |      5 |   2 |
+---------+----------------------------------------------+--------+-----+
```

I wrote a Visual Basic module to evaluate the equations:

```
Public Function eval(s As String) As Variant
    eval = Evaluate(s)
End Function
```

And basically, I just want to be able to insert the "val" column into the equation, and then multiply against the weight and get an array of sums.

I tried this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(H$7:H$31),Dist(H$7:H$31,$D$7:$D$31,$E$7:$E$31))
```

where Dist is a lambda function:

```
LAMBDA(val,eq,weight,eval(CONCAT("=",SUBSTITUTE(eq,"val",val))))
```

But anytime I have a table longer than 1 row, it yells at me with an #N/A or #VALUE error, presumably because the LOGNORM.DIST function doesn't like having more than 1 value.

Is there a way to coerce an excel function into taking an array?

Comment: Use, BYROW so the dist function only sees one value at a time?

Comment: i just know there is a way to do this, but BYROW only limits my lambda to one variable, when I need at least the "val" and "eq" values as parameters

Comment: Thank you for introducing BYROW to me. However, it doesn't fully solve my problem. I get that it goes row by row, applying a lambda to each row. However, I only get one parameter this way. I cannot specifically say "column B of this row is the equation, and column D is the value, plug the value in!"

Comment: I FIGURED IT OUT! The MAP function is basically BYROW, except you can add more columns to the input. I got exactly what I needed. Thanks for leading me on the right trail

Comment: I was about to suggest to use `MAP` but you figured it out. I cannot test it because I use Excel web and you need Name Manager for that. I am glad it worked

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the comments, I solved this with the MAP function. Posting an answer for visibility. I navigated to Formulas > Name Manager and created a new formula called Dist that does this:

```
=LAMBDA(val,eq,MAP(val,eq,LAMBDA(val,eq,eval(CONCAT("=",SUBSTITUTE(eq,"val",val))))))
```

So now, that SUMPRODUCT formula I posted basically looks like this (pseudocode):

```
=SUMPRODUCT(IF(ISNUMBER(ValsColumn),Dist(ValsCol,EqColumn), ...if false), WeightCol)
```

This will correctly input values to each of my equations with no yelling about it being an array, since I think `Map` goes row by row. Hopefully this makes sense to anyone in the future...